# JUnit for future.get() Exception scenario

Tags: java, multithreading, junit4

I need to test `InterruptedException` and `ExecutionException` and write JUnits for the same.

Please advice me on this. How can i interrupt the threads to replicate the scenario. The `populateDataForm` will start new threads and add this to futures list.

Here is my sample code:

```java
class MyTest{
    public populateData(){

    Collection<Future<?>> futures = new LinkedList<Future<?>>();
    DataSet ds = Helper.populateDataForm(employee, futures);

    waitForTaskCompletion(futures);
    }


    private waitForTaskCompletion(futures){
    for (Future<?> future:futures) {
        try {
               future.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               throw new CustomExcpetion("Message1", e)
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
               throw new CustomExcpetion("Message2", e)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit from `MyTest` and overload `populateData()` method as follows:

```java
public void populateData() {

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Callable<String> calls = new Callable<String>() {

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            for (;;){
                Thread.sleep(100);
                // You call interrupt here, which causes Future.get() interrupt
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                if (1 > 2) break;
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    final Future<String> future = executorService.submit(calls);

    waitForTaskCompletion(future);
    executorService.shutdown();
}
```

To test the `ExecutionException` throw `RuntimeException` instead of the interrupt as follows:

```java
if (1==1)throw new RuntimeException();
```

Comment: Thanks Sqeezer for the advice. It worked really well for generating ExecutionException scenario, but I could not get the same exception message for InterruptedException when while writing my JUnit with @Rule.

Comment: For InterruptedException scenario testing with @Rule, we need to interrupt the thread running populateData() method. So, after invoking populateData() method from my test class, I interrupted the running thread with  Thread.currentThread().interrupt(). As the same thread which is running TestMethod is running the populateData() method and interruption of this thread is enough.